# How does keyword`in` works in iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, in-operator

I have this:

```
>>> 1 in (i for i in range(0, 5))
True

>>> 2 in (i for i in range(0, 5))
True
```

after that:

```
>>> gen = (i for i in range(0, 5))
>>> 1 in gen
True
>>> 3 in gen
True
>>> 2 in gen
False
```

Does keyword`in` works like:

```
3 in gen
```

is equal to:

```
j = 3
for i in gen:
    if i == j:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

but after for-loop, DO NOT RESET iterator TO FIRST again.

IS that right?

Comment: When I run your second example in python 2.7 and python 3, I get a `NameError: Name 'i' is not defined`.  Are you sure you didn't define i somewhere earlier in the interpreter session?

Comment: @happydave My fault, I did really see that result before, but just now , I test the code, I got your result. Maybe I write `i` in that test. Correct it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generators maintain the context when they yield a value. So, when you do

```
1 in gen
```

it will begin iterating and when it reaches `1`, it returns `True`, but the current state is at `1`. Next, when you do `3 in gen`, it iterates till `3` and yields `True`. And then when you do

```
2 in gen
```

it begins iteration from `3`, not from the beginning. That is why you are getting `False`.

In your program,

```
j = 3
for i in gen:
    if i == j:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

if `i` is not equal to `j`, it will immediately return `False`. Instead, it can be loosely understood as,

```
return any(i == j for j in gen)
```

`any` iterates the generator until any of the items match the criteria. If none of the items match, it will exhaust the generator and will return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

The *in* operator works like the *f_in* function defined below:

```
def f_in(aj, gen):
    j = aj
    while(True):
        try:
            if(j == gen.next()):
                return True
        except StopIteration:
            return False
mygen = xrange(5)
agen = iter(mygen)

print f_in(1, agen)
print f_in(3, agen)
print f_in(2, agen)
```

This makes a lot of sense since an iterator could be infinite and a successful call of the kind *3 in it* has not need to loop over the whole (potentially infinite) iterator.

Answer (score -1):

[From the docs on the Python data model:](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

> The membership test operators ([`in` and `not in`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in)) are normally implemented
>   as an iteration through a sequence.

it starts iterating through the iterator until it gets to the item, and returns `True`, or exhausts the iterator and returns `False`. If the iterator is not exhausted, you may still get the remaining items from it, but that does not restart the generator, and you'll only iterate through the remaining elements.